# I need to print static matrix overloading "<<" operator

Tags: c++

I need to print static matrix overloading "<<" operator. Here is my code:

```
    class Matrix 
{
public:
    int matrix[3][3];
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Matrix& e);
};

 std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Matrix& e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
        {
            out << e.matrix[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        out << std::endl;
    }
    out << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

and main function

```
int main
{
int A[3][3] = { {1,1,1},{1,0,0},{0,0,1} };
}
```

My problem is I don't know how to use in main function my overloaded operator to print matrix A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't know how to use in main function my overloaded operator to print matrix A

First, you need to create an instance of your `Matrix` class, then you can print it:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix A = {{{1,1,1}, {1,0,0}, {0,0,1}}};
    std::cout << A;
}
```

Side note: I suggest replacing all `out << std::endl;` with `out << '\n';` in your `operator<<`. You should let the user [`std::flush`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/flush) if the user actually needs it.